# npm run local binaries on windows

Tags: windows, npm

How can you run local npm binaries on Windows(10)?

I'm trying to run a webpack dev-server(using webpack-encore in this instance)
`npm run dev-server`

**package.json snippet:**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server --hot --port 8002",
  }
}
```

and receive the following error:

`'encore' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I tried `./node_modules/.bin/encore` and any variation I could think of to the same effect.

**Please do not suggest installing globally, as that fails for more esoteric reasons.**

`npm -v 5.4.2`

Comment: Did you get that error by using `npm run dev-server`?

Comment: @lilezek Correct. I'll edit.